# Facebook Graph API limit - per token and per IP?

Tags: facebook

So I am using the Facebook Graph API. The documentation specifies the rate limit is 600 calls per 600 seconds, per token & per IP. I don't understand what this means, so tell me if these examples will pass the valid rate limits:

**Example 1:**
I have 2 access tokens (for 2 users). I am calling from 1 IP address. Can I make 1200 total calls in 600 seconds, 600 calls for each access token?

**Example 2:**
I have 1 access token, I am calling from 2 IP addresses (600 per IP address), can I make 1200 total calls in 600 seconds?

Comment: Assuming the calls you're making don't also hit CPU usage limits, which are harder to determine, example 1 is correct; the IP limit only applies when no access token is provided

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It all depends on what kind of limit you're hitting. If it's a "User request limit reached" then using a different access token would suffice. However, there's also a global app-level API limit that (to my best understanding) doesn't take into account your DAU number.

Once you hit "Application request limit reached", all user tokens generated by that application cease to work for the duration, and even OAuth logins stop working (!!!).

Answer (score 8):

I checked the Facebook rate limits and found that both examples are correct. Facebook uses the (token, IP address) pair as unique identifier. You could use 2 access tokens per 1 IP address and 1 access token from 2 IP addresses. In both cases you will make 1200 total calls without any problems.

The rate limit doesn't depend on access token type (app access token, page access token etc) and it doesn't take into account the person who get this access token.

Comment: How about if I have 10 tokens and 1 IP—6000 reqs? really? or even 1 IP and 100 tokens? 60 000 reqs?

Comment: You are able to make (IP * Tokens * 600) requests per second