# Api rate limit for business or app within the business

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Dose Facebook limits total api calls (600 call per 600 seconds) for each app separately within one business or the limit apply for all the apps within a business?

for example:
i have a business with 6 apps, each app can make 600 calls per 600 seconds?
or
each app can make 100 calls?

Answer (score 0):

Limits are per App/Token/IP afaik, so it´s always good to use a User or Page Access Token instead of an App Access Token or even no Token at all. But the limit is dynamic, there are no static numbers. And you are not allowed to use several App just to circumvent the API Limit.

More information: [What's the Facebook's Graph API call limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8713241/whats-the-facebooks-graph-api-call-limit)

Comment: i read all the answers i could find. no one talks about business only apps.  

  
also this answer says otherwise: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13983033/facebook-graph-api-limit-per-token-and-per-ip

Comment: there are no "business only apps". there are just apps.

Comment: from what i understand, i can create new app ==> generate new token ==> and the limit will only apply on that app.

Comment: We do limitations on IPs and other stuff also. So creating more apps just to bypass the limitations will not work

Comment: @WizKid creating new IP addresses is not a problem, what "other stuff"?

i just need to be sure that if i got several apps the limit will be calculated for each app separately

Comment: as long as you don´t try to circument api limits by using multiple apps, and as long as you don´t do unneccessary calls and create serious apps, there should be no problem at all with limits.

Comment: @WizKid im not trying to abuse or find a way to do so, the documentation on Facebook API limit rate is very poor and not clear. im just trying to understand whats the real limits, because it will affect the software design

Comment: it´s not very clear because there´s nothing to say. there are no static limits, you can´t just get a static number. 600 calls per 600 seconds is only a general rule.